# О термине "второстепенное значение букв"

Tags: русская-графика

Хотелось бы узнать историю термина "второстепенное значение букв": во-первых, когда он появился в лингвистике и, во-вторых, когда стал изучаться в школе?

Мне он кажется немного надуманным, но, может быть, я ошибаюсь. Я даже думаю, что это не очень полезное упражнение, которое способно затуманить сознание школьников. Вот всем знакомый алфавит: буква А обозначает звук А.  Но без проверки обозначаются только звуки в сильных позициях, а в слабых (безударных) звук надо проверить, так как это редуцированный звук, удобный для произношения, но с ограниченными смысловыми возможностями.

Эта простая и всем понятная  схема отражает фонематическую сущность нашего письма, отличая его от письма фонетического. Как-то не укладывается сюда это "второстепенное значение букв". Разве не проще указать слабые и  сильные позиции ЗВУКА, а не искусственно придумывать разные значения БУКВ.

И еще здесь, как мне кажется, ощущается влияние Петербургской фонологической школы (ПФШ), которая понемногу оттесняет МФШ.

Comment: Вы считаете, что графику учить не нужно, это надуманная наука? А может, она  проясняет некоторые исключения из правил в русском языке?Хотя ей нельзя руководствоваться в правописании, для этого есть орфография. Но грамотному человеку интересно понаблюдать и за графикой.И за употреблением ё, е,э, й, ы.Интересно задуматься и над тем, что внешне сходные начертания букв в русском и латинском, например, обозначают разные звуки. Слова, написанные по-русски, читаются по-латыни совсем по-другому: репа-пена, сироп-купон,роса-пока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я никакой специалист, термина этого не знал, но объяснения Людмилы меня вообще ввели в ступор. Из чего я делаю вывод, что термин таки надуманный.

Если из определения непонятно, какие "значения" (а что это вообще такое?) называются главными, какие второстепенными, то как быть?
Значение буквы - некоторый звук, ей соответствующий? Ну допустим.
Т.е. "главное значение буквы" - некоторые "главные" звуки?
А неосновное значение буквы - "неглавные" звуки?
Как отличить главный звук от негланого?

Я даже не касаюсь терминов "фонема" и "аллофон".
Вот буква С может передавать с десяток разных звуков. 
С, С', Ж ("сжечь"), З' ("весь день"), З (сдоба), Ш (бесшовный), Щ (бесщелевой) и проч.
Какие значения главные? И почему?

> И вот двузначная буква Б еще имеет два основных значения и два второстепенных. Это мне кажется надуманным и искусственным.

Угу...

Comment: Вы тоже перешли на фонетику и фонологию, а мы их не касаемся, никакие фонемы нам в графике не нужны.Русское письмо звуковое.Графика устанавливает состав начертаний и звуковые значения букв. Анализируя графический вид слова, мы задаём вопрос: каково звуковое значение буквы Б в слове Бок?Какой звук она передаёт? -она передаёт звук [б], значит, её значение основное.Каково значение буквы Б в слове Пробка?-она передаёт звук [п], здесь она имеет второстепенное значение, потому что основное у неё передавать звук [б].Это не у звука значение, а у буквы.Слоговой принцип графики экономит буквы.

Comment: Людмила!!!   
Во-первых, я как раз никуда не переходил. Считайте, что я вообще таких слов не знаю.  
Во-вторых, за обилием информации я не получил ответа на единственный важный вопрос. По какому правилу Б и Б' - главные значения, а П и П'- второстепенные. 
 
>звуковое значение буквы   
  
Ну я и говорю. "Значение" буквы - это звук.  
  
>передаёт звук [б], значит её значение основное  
   
Откуда я это знаю? Буква В передаёт звук [в], значит это второстепенное значение? Или тоже основное?  
  
Кстати, "основное"  и "главное" (значение) вы употребляете как синонимы? Я жае это не понял.

Comment: Основное и главное- синонимы, конечно. Почитайте здесь, быстрее разберётесь:               http://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/fonetika-fonologia/grafika/znacheniya-bukv/4046/?q=463&n=4046               
http://distribut.net/article/a-239-2.html

Comment: Людмила, еще раз спасибо за ссылки и подбор информации.

Answer (score 1):

Большое спасибо всем, кто отвечал на вопрос, для меня ситуация несколько прояснилась.

1) Для начала интересно отметить , что БУКВЕННУЮ схему (основные и вспомогательные буквы) можно представить в виде ЗВУКОВОЙ схемы (основные и вспомогательные звуки).

Рассмотрим, например, слова "вода", его схема:  ОВОО.  О – это ОСНОВНОЙ (смысловой) звук-фонема в сильной позиции, В – это ВСПОМОГАТЕЛЬНЫЙ звук в слабой позиции. Такие звуки иногда называют звуками с неполной различительной способностью. В данном случае звук, имеющий акустику звука А, говорит нам о том, что в данной позиции могут находиться смысловые звуки-фонемы А или О, поэтому его следует проверить, а уже потом проверенный звук  обозначать буквой.

2) Но это МФШ, которую я бы назвала фонологической школой здравого смысла с возможностью практического применения в орфографии. Сейчас же на первое место, очевидно, выдвинулась бывшая ПФШ, а теперь новомосковская школа, где всё наоборот (а ведь совсем недавно ПФШ по большому счету даже не принималась всерьез).

3) Противостоять структуре, как известно, не имеет смысла, лучше по возможности ее не замечать и ей не противоречить. А термин, скорее всего, самый новый, уж очень странно выглядят обычные буквы, которым придается  "второстепенное значение".

Answer (score 0):

Это не школьный термин, графику изучают в вузах, как и слоговой принцип графики.

Появились термины в одно время с термином фонема, но признают его обе школы - и Московская, и Петербургская, мне они не кажутся надуманными. В школе стало уделяться большое значение фонетике (без термина фонема), а в вузе есть характеристика букв, а они бывают однозначными и многозначными. Роль буквы - обозначать звук. С точки зрения главных значений все буквы русского алфавита распределяются на две группы:

1) однозначные (а, о, у, э, ы; ж, ц, ч, ш, щ, и), всегда обозначающие один звук;

2) двузначные (е, ё, и, ю, я; б, в, г, д, з, к, л, м, н, п, р, с, т, ф, х), обозначающие два разных звука.

Например, буква б может обозначать как твердый, так и мягкий звук — [б] и [б'] (был — бил, бал — бел), буква я в одних случаях обозначает звук [а] после мягкого согласного, в других —сочетание [ja] (ср.: вяз — объять, дядя — яма); буква и может обозначать звуки [и] и [ы](чисто — жир, вид — цинк).

Если буква произносится в слове так же, как и вне его, то она выступает в основном значении. Если же произношение буквы в слове не совпадает с произношением вне его, то она выступает во второстепенном значении. Например, в словах час, пол, хлебный буквы а, о, б имеют основное звуковое значение; второстепенное значение буква а имеет в словах часы, часовой, буква о — в полы, половой, буква б — в хлеб.

Для графики важны главные значения букв, т. е. важно, какими средствами передается содержание слова.

Второстепенные же значения букв определяются их употреблением (правилами орфографии).

Так что ничего надуманного здесь нет.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за ответ и за ваше мнение, но все-таки меня настораживает вот какие вопросы.

(1) Буква Б может обозначать два звука Б (мягкий и твердый), это особенность русской графики, поэтому буква Б двузначная. Это правильно. И вот двузначная буква Б еще имеет два основных значения и два второстепенных. Это мне кажется надуманным и искусственным.

Comment: (2)А в слове "полы" буква О, которая как раз передает смысл слова и соответствует фонеме О, вдруг называется второстепенной. Этот термин мне не представляется правильным. (А ведь, кажется, ПФШ считает, что здесь фонема А). И когда в вузах появилась эта терминология?

Comment: Вы перепутали фонологию с графикой.Буква Б имеет два главных значения - обозначает мягкий и твёрдый звуки[б]и [б'], а может иметь второстепенное значение, когда обозначает глухой звук - гриб, зыбь. Что в этом искусственного? Изучение графики вообще носит прикладное значение, а не определяет правописание,его определяет другая наука - орфография. В слове"полы" буква О передаёт звук[а], а то,что соответствует фонеме О,в графике неважно, важно в фонологии,их путать не надо.Студентам-филологам это надо знать, школьникам не надо

Comment: Я не то чтобы путаю фонологию с графикой, но считаю, что фонология родилась из графики, но потом забыла об этом и стала считать себя независимой наукой. Ведь понятие фонемы возникло тогда, когда люди стали размышлять о разном произношении звуков в одной позиции (то А, то  О) и им нужно было выбрать форму письма (А или О). Но фонология не должна отрываться от своих корней, от практических нужд языка, иначе это будет пустая наука.

Comment: Вот пример: 2001 год, педагогический университет. Вдруг обнаруживается, что студенты на 5 курсе элементарно неграмотны, и для них срочно вводится курс орфографии. И это не будущие ученые-лингвисты, а будущие учителя-филологи. На первом курсе они писали работы на тему "Чем МФШ отличается от ПФШ", но теперь не могут ни сами грамотно писать, ни объяснить это  ученикам. Получилось, что время на изучение фонологии потрачено напрасно, и это при том, что русское письмо основано на фонологии.

Answer (score -1):

Сложно сказать, надуманный термин "второстепенные значения букв", или нет. Скажем, "спряжение" - совершенно искусственный термин (в языке нет соответствующего "естественного" понятия), но помогает в орфографии. Надо судить по практическому применению. Вы этот термин где-то на практике используете?

[[@Людмила](/users/247/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0)](/users/247/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0) и [@behemotus](/users/1988/behemotus), ну чесслово, как дети малые. Ну почитайте уже открытые источники (хотя бы в Википедии - Фонема). В процессе письменной речи участвуют две стороны: читающий и пишущий. Так и фонема бывает: для читающего и для пишущего. Для читающего: буква обозначает фонему. Для пишущего: ну, тут несколько сложнее.

[[@Vera](/users/4440/vera)](/users/4440/vera), никто никого никуда не оттесняет. МФШ и ЛФШ существуют только в наших головах - людей, трущихся на этом форуме. В реальной жизни давно о них забыли.